# Tomcat: Websocket broadcast in responce to http POST request

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, websocket

I need to broadcast messages via websocket, every time I get a specific POST request. The problem is that one servlet (extended HttpServlet) receives the POST request and the another one (extended WebSocketServlet) process the websocket connections.

I can't use RequestDispatcher (if I properly understand it) because of different request types and because of I need further processing request in the POST-received servlet.

I don't know if I can send ws-request from first servlet to second one, but even if I can it's not seems the right way...

Answer (score 1):

websockets require that you upgrade a http connection, and once that connection is upgraded you are no longer talking http, you are talking websocket.

so websockets do not have the concept of a http POST semantic

In theory, if you had two connections between point A and point B with one being http and one being websocket, you could coordinate that sort of setup custom like in the server but it would be a terrible design imo, way too much coordination involved.  far better to just use a message library like cometd where you can have back and forth messaging that is protocol agnostic.  then you let that message library decide if it should talk websocket or spdy or http with long polling or just plain ole http.